# SQL order by maintain variable order

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I've created a ranking query that orders by points, and then if its a draw it orders by date of creation. The problem is that when I use the date to order draws, it gets messed up.

**This was what I had first:**

```
SELECT 
    @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank,
    sticker_id,
    total_shared,
    total_liked,
    total_used,
    total_shared+total_liked+total_used AS points,
    stickers.date
FROM( 
    SELECT 
        sticker_id,
        SUM(if(event_id = 1, 4, 0)) AS total_shared,
        SUM(if(event_id = 2, 2, 0)) AS total_liked,
        SUM(if(event_id = 3, 6, 0)) AS total_used
    FROM stickers_stats
    WHERE timestamp LIKE '2015-09%'
    GROUP BY sticker_id
) AS ranks 
JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
INNER JOIN stickers
    ON ranks.sticker_id = stickers.id
ORDER BY points DESC
```

RESULT:

[image: First result]

---

This was what I got after:

```
SELECT 
    @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank,
    sticker_id,
    total_shared,
    total_liked,
    total_used,
    total_shared+total_liked+total_used AS points,
    stickers.date
FROM( 
    SELECT 
        sticker_id,
        SUM(if(event_id = 1, 4, 0)) AS total_shared,
        SUM(if(event_id = 2, 2, 0)) AS total_liked,
        SUM(if(event_id = 3, 6, 0)) AS total_used
    FROM stickers_stats
    WHERE timestamp LIKE '2015-09%'
    GROUP BY sticker_id
) AS ranks 
JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
INNER JOIN stickers
    ON ranks.sticker_id = stickers.id
ORDER BY points DESC, stickers.date ASC
```

RESULT:
[image: Second result]

I've tried changing the order of how fields are shown and everything, but I can't find the solution. How to I order by `points` and `stickers.date` with new rank positions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL can get confused when you start mixing variables with other constructs.  I'm not sure what tips your query over the edge, but using a subquery should help:

```
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, t.*
FROM (SELECT sticker_id, total_shared, total_liked, total_used,
             (total_shared + total_liked + total_used) AS points,
             s.date
      FROM (SELECT sticker_id,
                   SUM(if(event_id = 1, 4, 0)) AS total_shared,
                   SUM(if(event_id = 2, 2, 0)) AS total_liked,
                   SUM(if(event_id = 3, 6, 0)) AS total_used
            FROM stickers_stats
            WHERE timestamp >= '2015-09-01' and timestamp < '2015-10-01'
            GROUP BY sticker_id
          ) r JOIN
          stickers s
          ON r.sticker_id = s.id 
     ) t CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @rownum := 0) params
ORDER BY points DESC, date ASC;
```

Also:

- Don't use `LIKE` for date/time values.
- Always use an `ON` clause with `JOIN`.  If you want a `CROSS JOIN`, be explicit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

I tend to like to force the order within the sub query. It still isn't certain to work (MySQL has some get out clauses on the order statements will be executed within a query), but seems more reliable.

In this case I would suggest that you do the join to stickers within the sub query as well:-

```
SELECT 
    @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank,
    sticker_id,
    total_shared,
    total_liked,
    total_used,
    total_shared+total_liked+total_used AS points,
    stickers_date
FROM( 
    SELECT 
        sticker_id,
        stickers.date AS stickers_date,
        SUM(if(event_id = 1, 4, 0)) AS total_shared,
        SUM(if(event_id = 2, 2, 0)) AS total_liked,
        SUM(if(event_id = 3, 6, 0)) AS total_used
    FROM stickers_stats
    INNER JOIN stickers
    ON stickers_stats.sticker_id = stickers.id
    WHERE YEAR(timestamp) = 2015
    AND MONTH(timestamp) = 9 
    GROUP BY sticker_id, stickers_date
    ORDER BY points DESC, stickers_date ASC
) AS ranks 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
ORDER BY points DESC, stickers.date ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me a lot. Gordon was faster ;)

Comment: No problem. Gordons answer is likely fine as well and he deserves the accept, I just prefer to force the order within the sub query to make it more explicit that it is counting over an already ordered set of data.